What is this usage of まで?
小さな笑いが漏れた。けれどぎこちなく、一生懸命に応えようとする彼女の姿は可愛らしい。
"初々しいのは慣れるまでなんだろうけど"
呼び続ければいつか港、香、と言うのが当たり前になる。
The character is trying to his lover to call him by first name, but she can't.
I understand
"小さな笑いが漏れた。けれどぎこちなく、一生懸命に応えようとする彼女の姿は可愛らしい。"
"He let out  a small laugh. Her figure trying to answer is cute"
and
呼び続ければいつか港、香、と言うのが当たり前になる。
if they continue calling each other Kaori and Minato will be natural.
What is "初々しいのは慣れるまでなんだろうけど"  までなんだろうけど here?


[初々]{ういうい}しいのは[慣]{な}れるまでなんだろうけど。

This ～まで is "(lasts) until (the time)～". 「～(の)は‥‥まで」 means "It is only until ‥‥ that ～", "～ lasts only until ‥‥"
初々しいのは慣れるまで(だ) would mean "It will be only until we get used to it that we feel awkward" "The freshness/awkwardness will last only until we get accustomed to it." i.e. The freshness will fade away after we get accustomed to it.
～なんだろうけど。(＜なのだろうけど) means "I guess ～～, though."
